# How Callback is maintained from Userspace to Kernel Space

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, watchdog, gpio

I am learning about the driver and looking into the watchdog  driver code  where some value is being written to `/sys/devices/virtual/wdc_per` now I guess this is the logic how driver gets its value from userspace and exposed file in user space is

```
 "sys/devices/virtual/wdc_per"
```

But now how actually this value from wdc_per is reached to driver, there must some callback maintained

In My case its GPIO based Watchdog driver and gpio_wdt.c may be having this callback.

But I really could not figure out how it actually happens

Anybody can help me find out this userspace to kernel space link.

Comment: can you share us the link for the code if it is big  ?.Just check whether there's ioctl system calls which usually transfer the execution from user to kernel space .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this driver, `gpio_wdt.c`, doesn't seem to exist in the mainline kernel as of this date, so it's hard to comment it.

Sysfs (usually mounted at `/sys`) is actually very easy to use. [This](http://godandme.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/how-to-make-a-sysfs-entry/) is a great example of how to create Sysfs attributes. Basically, you create attributes (will become the Sysfs file names) and register them with two defined operations (callbacks): *store* and *show*, which are the equivalent of resp. *write* and *read*. The *show* callback is called everytime the Sysfs file (attribute) is read and *store* when it's written.

When writing a device driver that belongs to an existing class (most likely your situation), you will rarely need to do that yourself. This is because the standard Linux device classes already have a working set of Sysfs attributes that your driver will use more or less indirectly.

For example, the `leds` class (LED devices), of which you will find the devices in `/sys/class/leds`, has a bunch of Sysfs attributes per LED so that a user may read/modify them from userspace (brightness, maximum brightness, trigger, etc.). Now, if you look at LED specific drivers in [`/drivers/leds`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/), you won't find manual Sysfs attributes creations. You will find, however, a call to `led_classdev_register` when the driver is probed, which takes a `struct led_classdev*` as a parameter. This structure has a `brightness_set` callback member the specific driver needs to provide. When a user writes to `/sys/class/leds/whatever-led/brightness`, the `leds` class' *store* Sysfs callback gets called which in turn calls the specific driver's `brightness_set` callback.

My point is: make sure you really know your device class before manually adding Sysfs attributes. Anyway, when submitting your driver to the LKML, you will know fast enough if it was a good decision.